# Excel Pick random value in range that is between dates

Tags: excel, random, countif

I have my example setup like the image below:

[image]

I'm trying to make a formula in cell F3 that will:

*"Select a random EVENT between A2:A11 where the USER INPUT DATE (E3) is between the START(B2:B11) and FINISH(C2:C11) dates*

The only thing I can think of is:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C11,">="&E3,B2:B11,"<="&E3)
```

But that only returns the number of EVENTS that are possible to choose from.

Any input would be appreciated

AN EXAMPLE OF A FINAL VALUE FOR THIS WOULD BE EITHER:

Event 3 or Event 4 because 7/2/2012 occurs between the start and finish dates of both events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this formula:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF((E3>=B2:B11)*(E3<=C2:C11),ROW(A2:A11)),
                  RANDBETWEEN(1,SUMPRODUCT((E3>=B2:B11)*(E3<=C2:C11)))
                )
      )
```

with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

1. `IF((E3>=B2:B11)*(E3<=C2:C11),ROW(A2:A11))` returns array of row numbers where `E3` falls between `START` and `FINISH` dates
2. `RANDBETWEEN(1,SUMPRODUCT((E3>=B2:B11)*(E3<=C2:C11)))` generates rand number between `1` and count of appropriate events
3. `SMALL(IF(..),RANDBETWEEN(..))` takes random row number from array from step 1.
4. `INDEX(A:A,SMALL(..))` gets corresponding event name.

Comment: First of all...this is amazing. The problem is that it either pulls "Event 2" which is not right, or it returns a value of "#NUM!". But this seems very very close.

Comment: Have you pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate formula or just ENTER?

Comment: Ah...thats the problem...You are correct Thank you!

Comment: @bagofmilk, btw, if there is no appropriate events, formula returns `#NUM!`, howerver you can handle it like this: `=IFERROR(INDEX(...),"there is no such events")`

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered, but I wanted to provide a slightly different option that doesn't require array entry (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,LARGE(INDEX((B2:B11<=E3)*(C2:C11>=E3)*ROW(A2:A11),),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIFS(B2:B11,"<="&E3,C2:C11,">="&E3)))),"No events found on that date")
```

And here is a backwards compatible version of the formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B11<=E3),--(C2:C11>=E3))=0,"No events found on that date",INDEX(A:A,LARGE(INDEX((B2:B11<=E3)*(C2:C11>=E3)*ROW(A2:A11),),INT(RAND()*SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B11<=E3),--(C2:C11>=E3)))+1)))
```